# Alternative to fastaread function in matlab

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics

I am trying to run  matlab code which uses the function [`fastaread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/fastaread.html), available in the  bioinformatics toolbox which I lack. I am wondering if I can make my own function which reads data from `.fasta` files function in order to run this code.

I am sorry for such unspecific naive question. But any help will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

Thank you for your response. I renamed readfasta.m from mbetoolbox to fastaread.m. However I am getting the following error:

```
??? Error: File: /home/users/fastaread.m Line: 85 Column: 1
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Error in ==> calculate_cons>read_alignment_fasta at 111
full_alignment = fastaread(msa_fasta_filename);

Error in ==> calculate_cons>read_alignment at 67
[encoded_focus_alignment, focus_index_of_interest, focus_to_uniprot_offset_map]
= read_alignment_fasta(msa_fasta_filename, seqid_of_interest);

Error in ==> calculate_cons at 41
[Pij_true, Pi_true, alignment_width, q, encoded_seq_of_interest,
focus_to_uniprot_offset_map] = read_alignment(msa_fasta_filename,
seqid_of_interest, theta);
```

I would appreciate your kind help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does this function do? Provide a little more background

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `readfasta` function in the [`mbetoolbox`](http://bioinformatics.org/mbetoolbox/).

Comment: If you *must* rename something, change the names in your existing function *from* `fastaread` *to* `readfasta`, provided that they take the same arguments and perform the same task.  Make sure the `mbetoolbox` is in your `PATH`, as well.